# What are the Issues when Java Server Socket run continuously

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

As part of our project we implemented Java Server Socket based application which will run between 06:35 Am to 11:59 Pm. After 11:59 Pm we are stopping this process and restarted at 06:35 Am.
Now we have a requirement to run this process continuously except in weekends.
The problem is if we run this process continuously, Do we get problem
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused? If we continuously run this job, Is the Socket will be Timeout? My requirement is in Production this process should not throw any errors because of continuously run.
Kindly advise?

Code:

```
SocketConnection socketConnection = new SocketConnection();
ServerSocket serverSocket = socketConnection.getSocketConnection();
while (true)
{
   Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
   ServerThreadHandler serverThreadHandler = null;
   try
   {
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
       String requestXml = in.readLine();
       //TODo the process
       out.println(responseXml);
   } catch (Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```

Regards,
Kiran T

Comment: Have you considered testing it?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically there is no problem with a `ServerSocket` accepting continously. But don't you need to `close` the `socket` you get from `serverSocket.accept()`?

You should check the documentation. If you need to close and you are not closing it, you might run out of resources and eventually get errors.

If you are already getting exceptions, please add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: Of course he needs to close it. It's a system resource, it's Closeable, it has a close() method.